# Attempted import error: 'useTranslation' is not exported from 'react-i18next'

Tags: reactjs, react-i18next

i need help
i got this error

```
./src/components/Header/Header.js
Attempted import error: 'UseTranslation' is not exported from 'react-i18next'.
```

its a new projects where i have install the https://react.i18next.com step by step
but i got problem with the import **UseTranslation**

in header.js i got just this

```
import { useTranslation } from 'react-i18next';
//style
import "./Header.scss";


class Header extends Component {
  
  render() {


    const { t, i18n } = useTranslation();

    return (
      
      <div className="container-header">
        <div className="container-header__main">
          <div className="container-header__main-overlay">
            <div className="container-header__main-overlay__text">
              <div className="container-header__main-overlay__text__title">
         
                {t('hello')}
              </div>
              <div className="container-header__main-overlay__text__subtitle">
                  {t('hello2')}
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Header;
```

---

this is my i18n.js this is ok i think

```
import i18n from "i18next";
import { reactI18nextModule } from "react-i18next";

import EN from './assets/translation/en.json';
import CZ from './assets/translation/cz.json';

const resources = {
  en: {
    translation: EN
  },
  cz:{
      translation: CZ
  }
};

i18n
  .use(reactI18nextModule) 
  .init({
    resources,
    lng: "en",
    fallbackLng: "en",
    useSuspense: false,

  });

export default i18n;
```

Comment: Are you sure that's the right file, and you don't have another one called "Header.js" in another folder?

I ask because firstly the file you pasted looks like it should work, and secondly because the error refers to "Header.js" with a H, while you mentioned "header.js" with a h.

Comment: Your error states that your tried to import `UseTranslation` with a capital `U` but in your example it starts with a lower case `u` which would be correct. Names are case sensitive in javascript.

Comment: The line `import { useTranslation } from 'react-i18next';` is correct. I can't help but wonder if OP either pasted the wrong file with the same name, or if they simply fixed the casing while pasting it here.

Comment: @HusseinDuvigneau i dont have another file call "Header.js" its a component callet on my main app

Comment: @trixn like HusseinDuvigneau say the the line is ok i just copy pasted it from documentation on [react.i18next](https://react.i18next.com)

Comment: @Petr The issue is that you simply missspelled `useTranslation` and used a capital `U` instead of a lower case `u`. There error clearly shows you used a capital `U`.

Comment: @trixn i try to use U like u say its the same error

Comment: @Petr Yes it clearly says `UseTranslation` which is wrong. It has to be `useTranslation` with a lower case `u`.

Comment: Is it possible you have something in your configs which is messing with the case sensitivity behind the scenes? A bad regex somewhere?

Comment: @HusseinDuvigneau i dont really dont know i was going with the documentation step by step

Comment: @Petr I never said use `U`. You already used a capital `U` which is **wrong**. Use a small `u`.

Comment: @trixn u can see i use small U on Header.js i never use capital U its just write in error

Comment: @Petr The error clearly has a capital `U` in the error text which means you definitely used a capital `U`.

Comment: @trixn i can see it but i use the useTranslation just in header.js not in another file

Comment: @Petr The error is pretty verbose. There must be a file `./src/components/Header/Header.js` and in that file you tried to import `UseTranslation` from `react-i18next`. Please make sure you didn't already correct the error and that is still shows. Did you confirm that you rebuild you app correctly? Are you running a watch task?

Comment: @trixn if delet the import and the{t('hello')} and {t('hello2')} the webapplication run without problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `useTranslation` it use for `hook` but you use classComponent you shold use `Hoc`

```
import { withTranslation } from 'react-i18next';
   const  {t,i18n} =this.props

  {t('hello2')}
export default withTranslation()(Header);
```

and in your  index.js add Suspense

```
import React, { Component, Suspense } from 'react';

  <Suspense fallback={<div>Loading....</div>}>
   
   <App />//your Component

  </Suspense>
```

Comment: the same problem but now just with `./src/components/Header/Header.js
Attempted import error: 'withTranslation' is not exported from 'react-i18next'.`

Comment: try to import '{withTranslation}' from 'react-i18next' @Petr

Comment: @Petr Did you change anything in your webpack config? How did you install `react-i18next`?

Comment: @trixn nope i just install from npm install react-i18next i18next --save

Comment: @krimo npm uninstall react-i18next@legacy i18next didnt work

Comment: @krimo its still not working i think its someting with packege also if i do 
npm i react-i18next its install just v9. but the newest is v10

Comment: @Petr it works well with me try with {Trans} in   https://react.i18next.com/legacy-v9/step-by-step-guide

Comment: @krimo i uninstall all my packege from npm and try install it from yarn and use HOC now its working thanks without SUSPENSE